# Thread dumps and signals to get deadlocks with line numbers

Tags: java, android

I would like to get a thread dump, like a "kill -3" on my Android process, so I can see deadlocks. But, from the adb shell, I get "Operation not permitted," since my test phones are not rooted.

Are the deadlocks visible in the DDMS thread monitor?
But, line numbers are not available there.

Answer (score 0):

[here](http://quequero.org/Debugging_Deadlocks_on_Android) this article explains how to debug thread deadlock in android. Also adding some self logging might help catching the deadlocks. Plus if you app is doing some network/disk operations you might want to read on android `StrictMode`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html

Comment: Thanks, but the article requires a rooted phone. My test phones are not rooted, thus the "Operation not permitted."